# Display text when clicked on the Button of AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm working with android and I want to make an event on `AlertDialog` button. I want to change the text on the button dynamically, this is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Soto_Betawi.this);
            alert.setTitle("Payment");
            alert.setMessage("Total Price : Rp. " + total);
            final EditText input = new EditText(Soto_Betawi.this);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Change Due", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    cash = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                    change = cash - total;
                    //I want to set a text from the operation above in a text
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
            alert.setCancelable(true);
            alert.create().show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using AlertDialog, you can use Activity with Dialog theme and create your own layout. So that you can simply change the text with

`myButton.setText("your text");`

Comment: Do you have any great how to to acomplish the solution?

Comment: I didnt get you. It's very easy to create an activity with dialog theme.

Comment: @SeshuVinay I create the following code for my custom dialog. but the dialog doesn't appear. Am I need to create and intent in the manifest? http://www.evernote.com/shard/s201/sh/ba6efc06-3dd8-45c0-a65c-83b217e3e420/3728c0ab8c4dc1b7d4c2be60e77f71cf

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution for you:

```
(AlertDialog)dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
```

This Should give you positive button of the `AlertDialog`

So my assumption is

```
(AlertDialog)dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("Your Text");
```

should be your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create and show alertdialog from method:

```
public void showAlert(String txtPositiveButton) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Soto_Betawi.this);
    alert.setTitle("Payment");
    alert.setMessage("Total Price : Rp. " + total);
    final EditText input = new EditText(Soto_Betawi.this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton(txtPositiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            cash = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
            change = cash - total;
            //I want to set a text from the operation above in a text
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
        }
    });
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.create().show();
}
```

Comment: He wants text to be changed when the user clicks the positive button of AlertDialog